# Correct way to escape this HTML in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, escaping

I'm adding a very basic version of the Stackoverflow question formatting system to my app. I've got it to the point where this string:

```
_italic_ and **bold** and `@inline_code` and: \n    </code snippet>
```

becomes:

```
<i>italic</i> and <b>bold</b> and <span class="block-code">@inline_code</span> and: <br/>
<span class="block-code"></code snippet></span>
```

What is the correct and safest way to display this so that the bold, italic and span tags all become HTML tags but other tags are displayed as text?

Comment: Best way would be to use a markdown library instead of reinventing, then using an HTML tag whitelister to convert to a "safe" string, then just use the standard html_safe functionality of Ruby.

Comment: The only reason I didn't use a markdown library was because I wanted to have a crack at doing it myself. So if I wanted to whitelist certain tags how might I go about that? Also is html_safe appropriate when rendering user-generated content? Thanks

Comment: `"<strong>A</strong><div>b</div>".html_safe(tags: %w(strong em a))`

Comment: html_safe is fine if you do the part I said before that, e.g., the whitelisting of tags. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html, https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize, etc.

Comment: @max When was `html_safe` updated to take an object arg? I know `sanitize` does this, I wasn't aware `html_safe` did.

Comment: @DaveNewton will sanitize not remove the tags entirely? I still want to be able to display them as a string

Comment: @DannySantos Hm, probably.

Comment: Actually @DaveNewton you're correct - sanitize takes a hash html_safe takes no arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to swap the ampersands and less-than symbols for HTML entities...

```
string.gsub("&", "&amp;").gsub("<", "&lt;")
```

...and then wrap the ouput in `<pre>` tags.